# Illustrated anthology book of poetry, with one of the poems being about putting too much sugar in a baby's tea?

Tags: poetry, identification-request

I was given an illustrated book of lot of individual English poem in the 90s (book could have been older) with 'weird' poems for children. I think the illustrations might have been watercolour, and the poetry could have been aimed at preteens? All the poems had quirky/funny subjects/topics.

The one poem I remember was about a mother putting too much sugar in a baby's tea, and the picture was of massive 6ft tall baby who'd grown large from too much. I think the poem may have been in rhyming couplets? The baby complains that they are too big for the room/bed/etc.?

I've been looking for this book of poetry for the last ten years on and off, and I haven't found anything. Unfortunately I don't remember any more details, not even the ones suggested [here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info).

What was this book called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is ten years later but this was my favourite book as a kid.
"Don't Put Sugar in my Tea, Mom" in *[There's an Awful Lot of Weirdos in Our Neighborhood](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/076360299X)* Colin McNaughton and possibly Janet/Alan Ahlberg.

> Don't put sugar in my tea, Mum.
> Don't put sugar in my tea.
> I'm already fat,
> So there's enough of that.
> Don't put sugar in my tea.

[image: Image showing the huge baby and the mother shoveling sugar into the tea]

Comment: This is exactly right! Heck, I'm so happy about this  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Might it have been ‘ Tea in the Sugar Bowl, Potato in My Shoe’ by Michael Rosen and illustrated by Quentin Blake?

I’m not familiar with its contents, but it looks to be in the right wheelhouse?
[image]

Comment: you've jogged my memory a little but this is not it. The art style is similar, but I'm almost certain it's not illustrated by Quentin blake. Also this was a book of (separate, individual) poetry, not a single poem that tells a story.

Comment: I associate that art style with Ogden Nash FWIW